# how to open a pop up window via button click in asp.Net

Tags: c#, javascript

I am creating a website in asp.Net. I want to use a pop up window to perform actions. i have a pop up window which runs on a hyperlink.

I want to perform this action to be done on button click. Is there any way to perform this action programatically. How to perform this action.

My code is as follows:-

Html code:-

```
    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">
    Fade and Pop
    </a>
        <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness</h1>
        <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles                  here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

Javascript Function:-

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
  });

$.fn.reveal = function(options) {

    var defaults = {  
        animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: false, //if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
    }; 

    //Extend dem' options
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

    return this.each(function() {

        var modal = $(this),
            topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
            topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
            locked = false,
            modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

        if(modalBG.length == 0) {
            modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
        }           

        //Entrance Animations
        modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
          modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
            $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
            if(!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                }
                if(options.animation == "fade") {
                    modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                } 
                if(options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                    unlockModal()               
                }
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:open');
        });     

        //Closing Animation
        modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
          if(!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                        "opacity" : 0
                    }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                        modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                        unlockModal();
                    });                 
                }   
                if(options.animation == "fade") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "opacity" : 0
                    }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        unlockModal();
                    });                 
                }   
                if(options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                    modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                }       
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:close');
        });     

        //Open Modal Immediately
    modal.trigger('reveal:open')

        //Close Modal Listeners
        var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
          modal.trigger('reveal:close')
        });

        if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
            modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
            modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });
        }
        $('body').keyup(function(e) {
            if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
        });


        function unlockModal() { 
            locked = false;
        }
        function lockModal() {
            locked = true;
        }   

    });
}
```

Comment: please try to remove console error first.

Comment: it is running perfect on my side. i just want that data-raveal-id is called on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you can open a popup by something like this, here you can pass your html in `.html`:

```
    var customDialog = function (options) {
        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                        .html('<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />Test Checkbox<div style="margin-top: 15px; font-weight: bold;">' + options.message + '</div>')
                        .dialog({
                            modal: true,
                            title: options.title || 'Custom Popup Box', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                            width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                },
                            },
                            close: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                        });
};

$('#myButton').click(function() { customDialog({message: 'your input message '}); });
```

Now you can call this method, on button click etc

```
customDialog({message: 'Test Message'});
```

Check this  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6KwS/4/)
**[EDIT]** To call a jquery function from anchor  tag check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23QgH/)

Comment: but in my code what should i do open pop up by button click. now it is opening by using <a> tag in html